# Stop Windows 7 closing programs on Hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

For some reason, when i resume my Lenovo machine running Windows 7 after hibernation, all of my programs that were open, have all closed.

I was under the impression that hibernation takes a snapshot of your RAM and just resumes the session on wake?

I think this may be a recent issue, meaning it could be to do with a recent update?

I couldn't find any useful information around the web, hence the question.

The only restore points on my PC are from 2 days ago, from a Critical Update and I believe the issue has been occurring longer than that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe there is a limit to the size of the hibernate file? Is the size of the hibernate file the same as your RAM size?

Comment: Is it really hibernating? I don't recall specific message, but is it showing `Resuming from hibernation ?` message at logon screen? See System log to confirm if it's resuming.

Comment: It definitely sounds like either your are not hibernating at all, or the hibernation file is getting corrupted and deleted, or possibly even something is preventing from the hibernation process from completing correctly. You’ll need to provide some more information/feedback to diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for some reason on Windows 8.0 64bit. I opened a cmd window with administrative privileges and did 'powercfg -h off" , enter and then 'powercfg -h on' and it re-created the hiberfil.sys file. Now it resumes from hibernate fine, so far. Will report back if it starts acting cup again.